# Create pcolormesh from 1D array

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 1D array `C = [1.0, 1.0, 0.93, 0.6, 0.28, 0.42, 0.53, 0.5, 0.42, 0.45]` and want to display it visually with Matplotlib. I tried using `pcolormesh`, but it only seems to work with 2d arrays like `C2D = [C[5:], C[:5]]`. This 2D array creates the following plot:

[image]

However, what I want is something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply turn you 1D list into a 2D matrix with just one row:

```py
plt.pcolormesh([C])
```